# Google Blogger Integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, blogger

Trying to just retrieve blog post and print the contents to a site. I am using the printFeed method from the documentation but it just seems to print the title. I need the title,body,photos,comments,etc.

```
function printFeed($feed)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($feed->entries as $entry) {
        print $i ." ". $entry->title->text . "\n";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I used `print_r()` on the array put it was just a mess of variables. I can't find any information on this. I also use the query function to limit my data and that throws errors. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

<del>For testing, you should be able to use the `toArray()` function</del>

<del>`print_r($entry->toArray());`</del>

This should show you the variables. You can access them in the object format similar to what you used for the title:

```
echo $entry->body;
```

Hopefully this helps. You will need to add the other items as well that you wish to print. <del>The `toArray()` method above is meant as an illustration, but if it is easier for you to understand how to work an array, you can assign that to a variable, but the object should work just as well.</del>

**EDIT**

I was mistaken about the `toArray()` call. Either or, does the `$entry->body` or `$entry->body->text` get you that information you need?

Comment: Plantation Building

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Property body does not exist' in /home/plant/public_html/includes/classes/Zend/Gdata/App/Base.php:484 Stack trace: #0 /home/plant/public_html/skin/plantation-building.php(25): Zend_Gdata_App_Base->__get('body') #1 /home/plant/public_html/index.php(236): include('/home/plant/pub...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/plant/public_html/includes/classes/Zend/Gdata/App/Base.php on line 484